# Differences between textMultiLine and textLongMessage

Tags: android, android-edittext

¿In what case do I have to use which of them?

In google documentation says:

**textMultiLine**
Can be combined with text and its variations to allow multiple lines of text in the field. If this flag is not set, the text field will be constrained to a single line.

**textLongMessage** Text that is the content of a long message.

But I wish use an *EditText* which will is multiline and with the content of a long message.

[inputType Google documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3ainputType)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use multiple tags e.g.

```
android:inputType="textMultiLine|textLongMessage"
```

Comment: Ah, ok. But, ¿what adds textLongMessege to a simple textMultiLine? They should be different in something.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29220766/5923973

Based on that answer and trying different options I can say:

**textMultiLine**: will give you the possibility to add break lines to your text from the keyboard.

**textLongMessage**: will make the TextInputEditText to change its height based on its content. So if the text reaches the end of the edit text, then the following words will go below making the edit text to increase the height.