# Android EditText inputType textShortMessage

Tags: android, android-inputtype

What is the purpose of inputType [`textShortMessage`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType.html#TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_SHORT_MESSAGE)? How will this affect my application?  Do certain keyboards, Android versions or applications treat this specially, or differently from just type `text`?

Comment: I tried it and saw no difference on my specific device with my specific Android version with the specific application I was using. I imagine the behaviour could be very nuanced and difficult to notice from a few uses.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not that much difference between `text` and `textShortMessage`. While developing the Android Source, google developers felt to create two different class for two different cases. textShortMessage and textLongMessage both inherits the behaviour of text with some different attributes.

There could be so many types of input for a EditText. Android Developer made it easier for us to define the behaviour of a specific EditText.

**textShortMessage is for:** *Variation of TYPE_CLASS_TEXT: entering a short, possibly informal message such as an instant message or a text message.*

It means when we use **textShortMessage** as input type the EditText will open the alphabetic keyboard but the EditText will not be Expanded. If you change it to **textLongMessage** the EditText will be expanded for multiline text input.

SOURCE: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType.html

Comment: I linked to that source in my very question - it is not descriptive. I know the difference between long and short, but what is the difference between `text` and `textShortMessage`, for example?

Comment: Not that much difference between them. While developing the Android Source, google developers felt to create two different class for two different cases. `textShortMessage` and `textLongMessage` both inherits the behaviour of `text` with some different attributes.

Comment: Can you put that as the answer? It is the actual answer to my question: "No difference"

Answer (score 9):

One difference :

```
android:inputType="textShortMessage|textMultiLine"
```

Will give you the smiley button in preference to the enter key.

```
android:inputType="textMultiLine"
```

Will give you the "enter" key again.

Comment: Thanks so much! I was so confused about why the smiley button was showing up despite setting correct ime options.

Comment: Can you explain other types also?